# Span multicolumn stats for LaTeX table with esttab/estout

Tags: latex, stata

I would like to be able to center a statistic over multiple columns when using `esttab`.

In my toy example, I would like `N` to span two columns:

```
sysuse auto, clear

est clear
qui estpost sum if foreign == 1
qui est store sum_foreign
qui estpost sum
qui est store sum_all

esttab sum_foreign sum_all, ///
    replace ///
    cells("mean(fmt(3)) sd(fmt(3))") ///
    nonum ///
    collabels("Mean" "SD") ///
    label ///
    noobs ///
    drop(make) ///
    stats(N, ///
        fmt(%9.0fc) ///
        label("Observations"))
```

Though the toy example just uses Stata's output, in general I would like to do this in LaTeX.

For other pieces of the table (`collabels`, `mgroups` etc.) you can specify the `pattern()` argument, which allows you to span, but this is not an option for `stats()`.

Does anyone know how I can make the observation count span the width of the model (2 columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually insert the required spacing between each statistic with `estadd`, using the appropriate LaTeX markup as a prefix. This is necessary in order to typeset the table correctly.

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

est clear
estpost sum if foreign == 1

local N1 \hspace{1.2cm}`e(N)'
estadd local NA `N1'

est store sum_foreign
estpost sum

local N2 \hspace{2cm}`e(N)'
estadd local NA `N2'

est store sum_all

esttab sum_foreign sum_all using table.tex, ///
    replace ///
    cells("mean(fmt(3)) sd(fmt(3))") ///
    nonum ///
    collabels("Mean" "SD") ///
    label ///
    noobs ///
    drop(make) ///
    stats(NA, ///
        fmt(%9.0fc) ///
        label("Observations"))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's another way of doing this but with automatic centering of the observation numbers:

```
sysuse auto, clear

est clear
estpost sum if foreign == 1

local N1 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{`e(N)'}

estadd local NA `N1'
est store sum_foreign

estpost sum

local N2 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{`e(N)'}

estadd local NA `N2'
est store sum_all

esttab sum_foreign sum_all using table.tex, ///
    replace ///
    cells("mean(fmt(3)) sd(fmt(3))") ///
    nonum ///
    collabels("Mean" "SD") ///
    label ///
    noobs ///
    drop(make) /// 
    postfoot("\hline Observations: `N1' `N2' \\ \hline\hline \\ \end{tabular} \\ }")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Pearly Spencer. This seems like an okay approximation, but I'd like to find a solution that more precisely centers the statistic if it's possible (or is something that can be generalized).

Comment: @AlexanderVornsand see the edit in my answer for a slightly more generalized solution.